# CSS input shifted to right

Tags: html, css

If you visit http://haywardconstruction.co.uk/newsubcontractor/ there is a form there and if scroll down to the "Email" input field this is where the problem is. For some reason the "Email" field is shift to the right and I need it to look like the other fields. I have compared the fields CSS with the other fields and they are the same. So I am not sure why this field is shifted to the right.

Comment: Please provide HTML and CSS code in code blocks so we can take a further look at the problem.

Comment: You simply need to apply a `float: left` to the field in question. As for exactly **why** that's having the issue, I honestly can't say.

Comment: The issue is that you have a bunch of whitespace before the `input`. When you use `inline-block`, which is what your inputs are using, the whitespace is taken into account.

Comment: Wow, you are correct @APAD1 I have never faced this issue before. Thank you so much for explaining that.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jay is right here - nothing else is causing the email input box to be positioned in the center. If you change the CSS white-space attribute to "nowrap" or "normal" on .ginput_container it will fix it. From the CSS:

```
 body .gform_wrapper .top_label div.ginput_container {
    white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of whitespace before that input box. Simply remove this whitespace and it will line up properly. This happens due to the fact that

```
display: inline-block;
```

takes into account whitespace.

Comment: I think it is the `white-space` CSS attribute with a value of `pre` rather than the `display` attribute which is causing the rendering of the preceding whitespace characters. Nevertheless, it is the preceding whitespace that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `whitespace: pre;` caused by the tags `<pre class="language-html"><code>`. Remove those tags, and their closing partners ones as well: `</pre></code>` from your HTML and you're good to go.

No idea what the intention is so for those tags, but I'm assuming that it's a legacy from some copy and paste.